# Create a ZIP archive with PowerShell and Windows tools

Tags: c#, .net, windows, powershell, zip

I would like to backup data of client computers with PowerShell. To do so I create a ZIP archive of the requested data which basically is no problem at all. But when it comes to special characters which use Unicode or the users build very long path names I run into trouble. I have tried different things now but haven’t found a solution yet. My client computers run Windows 10 (Build 1511). Installing the anniversary update (Build 1607) isn’t a solution due to other dependencies. Also the usage of 3rd party software to create ZIP files can’t be one.

Below are three methods I’ve found and tried already. They all have the same problems in common: when it comes to long path names they immediately stop the execution or they just skip the rest of the folder structure.

**1. Create a ZIP file with PowerShell V5 CmdLet Expand-Archive**

```
$Target = "C:\Temp\Test.zip"
$Source = "C:\Test"
Compress-Archive -Path $Source -DestinationPath $Target
```

**2. Create a ZIP file with .net class**

```
Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
$Target = "C:\Temp\Test.zip"
$Source = "C:\Test"
[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($Source, $Target);
```

**3. Create a ZIP file with Windows Explorer (Compressed Folders)**

```
$Source = Get-ChildItem "C:\Test" -Recurse
$Target = "C:\Temp\Test.zip"

if (-not (Test-Path $Target)) {
 Set-Content $Target ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))
 (dir $Target).IsReadOnly = $false  
}
$objShell = New-Object -Com Shell.Application
$objZIP = $objShell.NameSpace($Target)

foreach($File in $Source) { 
 $objZIP.CopyHere($File.FullName)
 Start-sleep -milliseconds 500
}
```

Then I found out, that it should be possible to access the local drives via UNC namespace which could look like `\\?\C:\Test`. But this doesn’t work with my Windows 10 build 1511 version. With build 1607 it is possible. What I don’t understand: why? I tried it with installing the latest .net version 4.6.2 on build 1511 but the problem still exists.

Can anybody help me with the access to (local) UNC namespaces or creating ZIP archives?

Answer (score 1):

to access UNC path, use the $ characters to design drive

like \\computername\c$\path\path\file.txt

i use the .Net function because of compatibility with powershell v2

```
[IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($SourcesFolder, $zipTempPath, $CompressionLevel, $False)
```

i use it with long UNC path with no problems.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Not sure if I tried it before with the .net class.

However, when I do that with UNC path and the network computer name, I get the typical path too long exception with long path or file names. From my experience it just works when you use the local UNC path (like '\\?\C:\...'). Could you try the local UNC path in PowerShell v2 and tell me if that works for you?

Comment: i don't get what you are seeking, by the way local path written like UNC also work. 
exemple : "\\localhost\c$\Users\Me\Desktop\test"
screenshot : http://imgur.com/RGNoKGC