# Compressing a file to a .ZIP in PowerShell v2.0

Tags: powershell

I want to zip a file using PowerShell v2.0 as I am engineering this code for a legacy server.

On my local machine running PowerShell v5.0 it works fine, but does not on PS v2.

Any idea how to ZIP a file using PS v2?

```
Compress-Archive -Path $root_folder\temp-file.csv -Update -DestinationPath $root_folder\temp-file.zip
```

Again, this is for PowerShell v2.0!

Comment: Possible related and duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153126/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-with-powershell, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40265627/create-a-zip-archive-with-powershell-and-windows-tools, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021879/creating-a-zipped-compressed-folder-in-windows-using-powershell-or-the-command-l, and a large number of others

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a zipped/compressed folder in Windows using Powershell or the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021879/creating-a-zipped-compressed-folder-in-windows-using-powershell-or-the-command-l)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a zip archive with PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153126/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-with-powershell)

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I have written a function to create a .zip file without the use of `Compress-Archive`

```
function createZipFile($outputFileName, $sourceDirectory){
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
    $compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal
    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($sourceDirectory, $outputFileName, $compressionLevel, $false)
}
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work for me. I got the error 
"Add-Type : Cannot add type. The assembly 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem' cou
ld not be found."